# Using simplemail in Haskell throws broken pipe error

Tags: excel, email, haskell

I have a Haskell program that I wrote over a year ago and has been running fine until a couple of months ago.

What changed? The program builds a series of Excel report files using SpreadsheetML (of which I am a contributor) and emails them as attachments to a list of users. The program is controlled by a comma separated text file where each line represents a single report and contains the report title, a list of database keywords (separated by |), and a list of recipient email addresses (also separated by |).

Three months ago this file was restructured to change what reports were generated and to whom they were distributed. Since then, one line in the file is killing the program with a broken pipe error. The error message from the program is:

```
CreateExcel: fd:7: hPutBuf: resource vanished (Broken pipe)
```

The program accepts a command line parameter to control whether or not to send the reports. If this parameter is False, the sendReport method (below) is never called and no error is reported. Therefore, I believe that everything before the call to sendReport is solid. Here is the code that produces the error:

```
makeAddress :: String -> Address
makeAddress addr = Address Nothing (T.pack addr)

sendReport :: String -> [String] -> String -> IO ()
sendReport file to title = do
    simplemail <- simpleMail (Address Nothing (T.pack "")) 
                       (Address Nothing (T.pack "")) 
                       (T.pack ("CDC/Groth Training Report: " ++ title)) 
                       (L.pack ("The attachment contains your training report for" ++ title ++ "."))
                       (L.pack ("The attachment contains your training report for <u>" ++ title ++ "</u>."))
                       [(T.pack "application/xml", file)]
    let mail = simplemail { mailFrom = Address (Just (T.pack "Order Fulfillment")) (T.pack "order_fulfillment@brindlewaye.com"), 
                            mailTo   = map makeAddress to, 
                            mailCc   = [], 
                            mailBcc  = [Address (Just(T.pack "Dave Smith")) (T.pack "dave@brindlewaye.pair.com")] }

    mailStream <- renderMail' mail
    sendmail mailStream
```

When the error is reported, the email does get sent, but without the Excel file attachment. Also, after reporting the error the program exits and none of the lines below it get processed.

The line from the report driver file that causes the crash is:

```
Sales-Europe-Africa, Sales/Thijssen|Sales/Pecqueur|Sales/van den Bos|Sales/Zuyderduyn|Sales/Marksman, user1@example.com|user2@example.com
```

... which translates to a report title of "Sales-Europe-Africa" and a list of database keywords and email recipients. If I change the report title to "TEST" it works; however, there is another line in the same file where the report title is "Sales-North-South-Americas" and that report runs fine.

Anybody see what I have missed?

Comment: I think the way you're building mails (with addresses empty at first) is a bit quirky, but I guess it should not matter.

Have you tried to use the in-memory version of simplemail to rule out lazy IO issues?

Comment: Just to be clear, the problem here occurs on one line of a 14 line file. If I put this line last in the file, 13 reports get generated and emailed without a problem. If I change the title of the report in this line, no error. Maybe I am stuck and not seeing it, but I can't imagine how changing the string that is the title of the report could crash the program. 

I feel silly just asking the question because it seems to me the this problem could not exist. Yet, I have been fighting it now for three months and just today realized that the report title is causing the crash.

It can't be, but is.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

Through a roundabout process, I found that simply rebuilding the application from its original source has fixed the problem. To accomplish the rebuild I had to reinstall a couple of the dependencies, but not one character of the original code was changed.

The new executable does not have the problem reported here. Thanks to all for your suggestions.

Comment: That's weird! Something must have gone really wonky, or maybe a bug was fixed in a package that you upgraded.